# How to make Netbeans window undecorated?

Tags: netbeans, gnome, titlebar

I'm using Netbeans IDE on tiny screen of my laptop, so I don't want to waste space for its titlebar. Is there any option in menus or command line that can remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (and most probably the only option) is to put NB into full screen mode. To do this you can use the `View > Full Screen` menu item (Alt + Shift + Enter).

Note that I'm running on Windows and I can't really say what Gnome will do with this.